# When I examine more than 9000 files with this Delphi code , I am having Error :stream Read Error

Tags: delphi

When I examine more than 9000 files with the following Delphi code, I get this error:

[image]

Please help me fix this error.

I use Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, and a MacBook with 8 gb RAM and an i5 CPU.

Freeandnill tested

Stream Free;
MemStr Free;
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details I have not more info

Tested

```
// detect image type

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  JPG_HEADER: array[0..2] of byte = ($FF, $D8, $FF);
  GIF_HEADER: array[0..2] of byte = ($47, $49, $46);
  BMP_HEADER: array[0..1] of byte = ($42, $4D);
  PNG_HEADER: array[0..3] of byte = ($89, $50, $4E, $47);
  TIF_HEADER: array[0..2] of byte = ($49, $49, $2A);
  TIF_HEADER2: array[0..2] of byte = (77, 77, 00);

type
  TImageType = (ifUnknown, ifJPG, ifGIF, ifBMP, ifPNG, ifTIF);

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TypeToStr(ImageType: TImageType): String;
begin
  case ImageType of
    ifJPG: Result := 'Image/JPEG';
    ifGIF: Result := 'Image/GIF';
    ifPNG: Result := 'Image/PNG';
    ifBMP: Result := 'Image/BMP';
    ifTIF: Result := 'Image/TIFF';
  else
    Result := 'Unknown Type';
  end;
end;

function GetImageType(FileName: String): TImageType;
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  MemStr: TMemoryStream;
  buf: integer;
  tmp: string;
begin
  Result := ifUnknown;
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  MemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MemStr.CopyFrom(Stream, 5);
    if MemStr.Size > 4 then
    begin
      // uncomment these lines to detect "unknown types"
      // MemStr.Position:=0;
      // MemStr.Read(buf,1);
      // showmessage(inttostr(ord(buf)));
      // MemStr.Read(buf,1);
      // showmessage(inttostr(ord(buf)));
      // MemStr.Read(buf,1);
      // showmessage(inttostr(ord(buf)));

      if CompareMem(MemStr.Memory, @JPG_HEADER, SizeOf(JPG_HEADER)) then
        Result := ifJPG
      else if CompareMem(MemStr.Memory, @GIF_HEADER, SizeOf(GIF_HEADER)) then
        Result := ifGIF
      else if CompareMem(MemStr.Memory, @PNG_HEADER, SizeOf(PNG_HEADER)) then
        Result := ifPNG
      else if CompareMem(MemStr.Memory, @BMP_HEADER, SizeOf(BMP_HEADER)) then
        Result := ifBMP
      else if CompareMem(MemStr.Memory, @TIF_HEADER, SizeOf(TIF_HEADER)) then
        Result := ifTIF
      else if CompareMem(MemStr.Memory, @TIF_HEADER2, SizeOf(TIF_HEADER2)) then
        Result := ifTIF;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    MemStr.Free;
  end;
end;

//Run Cod
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: String;
  it: TImageType;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    FileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;
    it := GetImageType(FileName);
    Label1.Caption := TypeToStr(it);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"Stream Free; MemStr Free; It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details I have not more info"* or with *"freeandnil tested"*?

Answer (score 5):

You are asking the `TStream.CopyFrom()` method to read *exactly* 5 bytes.  Internally, it uses the `TStream.ReadBuffer()` method, which raises a stream error if the *exact* number of bytes requested is not read.  For instance, if you try to read from a file that is less than 5 bytes in size.

In comments, you show that you have a loop that calls `GetFileSize()` before calling `GetImageType()`.  But that loop is checking the file size for `<> 0` when it should be checking for `>= 5` instead.  Your `TForm1.Button1Click()` method is not checking `GetFileSize()` at all before calling `GetImageType()`.

That being said, in `GetImageType()`, you don't need the `TMemoryStream` at all. Use a local `byte[]` array instead, and call the `TFileStream.Read()` method (not `ReadBuffer()`!) to populate it.  The return value tells you the *actual* number of bytes read.  Use that size when checking your image signatures.  You don't need `GetFileSize()` at all (which BTW, is easier to implement using `SysUtils.FindFirst()` instead of actually opening the file and querying its size).  `GetImageType()` should simply return `ifUnknown` if the requested file cannot be accessed (wrap the `TFileStream.Create` in a `try/except`) or is too small.

Try this:

```
type
  TImageType = (ifUnknown, ifJPG, ifGIF, ifBMP, ifPNG, ifTIF);

...

function TypeToStr(ImageType: TImageType): String;
begin
  case ImageType of
    ifJPG: Result := 'Image/JPEG';
    ifGIF: Result := 'Image/GIF';
    ifPNG: Result := 'Image/PNG';
    ifBMP: Result := 'Image/BMP';
    ifTIF: Result := 'Image/TIFF';
  else
    Result := 'Unknown Type';
  end;
end;

function GetImageType(FileName: String): TImageType;
const
  JPG_HEADER: array[0..2] of byte = ($FF, $D8, $FF);
  GIF_HEADER: array[0..2] of byte = ($47, $49, $46);
  BMP_HEADER: array[0..1] of byte = ($42, $4D);
  PNG_HEADER: array[0..3] of byte = ($89, $50, $4E, $47);
  TIF_HEADER: array[0..2] of byte = ($49, $49, $2A);
  TIF_HEADER2: array[0..2] of byte = ($4D, $4D, $00);
var
  Stream: TFileStream;
  buf: array[0..3] of Byte;
  bufsize: Integer;

  function MatchesSignature(const signature; signatureSize: Integer): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := (bufsize >= signatureSize) and CompareMem(@buf, @signature, signatureSize);
  end;

begin
  Result := ifUnknown;
  try
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      bufsize := Stream.Read(buf, SizeOf(buf));
      if bufsize < 2 then Exit;
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  except
    Exit;
  end;

  // uncomment these lines to detect "unknown types"
  // ShowMessage(IntToStr(buf[0]));
  // Showmessage(IntToStr(buf[1]));
  // Showmessage(IntToStr(buf[2]));

  if MatchesSignature(JPG_HEADER, SizeOf(JPG_HEADER)) then
    Result := ifJPG
  else if MatchesSignature(GIF_HEADER, SizeOf(GIF_HEADER)) then
    Result := ifGIF
  else if MatchesSignature(PNG_HEADER, SizeOf(PNG_HEADER)) then
    Result := ifPNG
  else if MatchesSignature(BMP_HEADER, SizeOf(BMP_HEADER)) then
    Result := ifBMP
  else if MatchesSignature(TIF_HEADER, SizeOf(TIF_HEADER)) then
    Result := ifTIF
  else if MatchesSignature(TIF_HEADER2, SizeOf(TIF_HEADER2)) then
    Result := ifTIF;
end;
```

Comment: this cod don't word plz re check

Comment: @oldman It works perfectly fine for me. If it is not working for you, you are not using it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You perform `MemStr.CopyFrom(Stream, 5);` without checking whether stream size is large enough.

So opening of empty or too short file gives that error.

Stream error arises due to reading beyond the end of file.

Try to check `Stream.Size` before copying

Comment: No, I use this function to check the files

 function GetFileSize(const FileName : string) : Int64;
var
  Reader: TFileStream;
begin
  Reader := TFile.OpenRead(FileName);
  try
    result := Reader.Size;
  finally
    //Reader.Free;
    //my cod
    freeandnil(Reader);
  end;
end;


if GetFileSize(ListBox1.Items[I]) <> 0 then
begin
 typefiles:=TypeToStr(GetImageType(ListBox1.Items[I]));
End;

Comment: `<> 0` is not equal to `>=5`

Comment: So code in question body is not real?

Comment: I explained in the text that this problem occurs when it is repeated

Comment: You have provided code with obvious mistake. It is certainly wrong code. But we cannot see how you repeat actions over 9000 times. Minimal **real** code would be useful.

Comment: When you speak about 9000 files, are you clicking `Button1` 9000 times, or is the code you show fake?

Comment: For i:=0 to listBox1.Count-1 do
begin
if GetFileSize(ListBox1.Items[I]) <> 0 then
begin
typefiles:=TypeToStr(GetImageType(ListBox1.Items[I]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[I] + 'c:\test\'+ typefiles + '\' + I.ToString+ '.' +  typefiles );
 end;
end;

Comment: Please @oldman, use the "edit" button under the delphi tag to edit your question.